# How can I search all the cloud drives I installed on my machine from windows search?

Tags: windows, search, cloud, icloud, search-indexing

How can I search cloud drives I installed from windows search?
I have iCloud + OneDrive + OneDrive business + Google Drive + Google Drive school.
And I want to search all of them via windows search. Is there any option for that? Or should I use the web for each to search for my files?

For example when searching for the image on my google drive via windows search:

```
IMG_10237.jpg
```

[I can't find the image even though my google drive is mounted to my laptop:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56b7P.jpg)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/56b7P.jpg

I can't find the image even though my google drive is mounted to my laptop as shown in [the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56b7P.jpg):
[image: I can't find the image even though my google drive is mounted to my laptop as shown in the image below:]

Comment: You can constrain (or not constrain) your search to All (not constrained), Documents (constrained and local) or Documents plus Web that should pick up Google documents.  Documents (local) will pick up Google  and One Drive that have local sync files.

Comment: how to do that? I tried to attribute all the drives to indexing nothing works :(

Comment: Windows Search has All  Documents Web ...   across the top of the Search sub window.  Indexing (Windows Indexing) works for local files so One Drive and Google Drive must have locally sync'd files.

Comment: no this is not working for me. check the picture I just sent.
https://imgur.com/a/QReI4Qq

Comment: I don't know then.  I use Drop Box and search that just fine.

Comment: Make sure for One Drive and Google (1) that the documents are normal documents (DOC, EXCEL and like) and the folders are in your USERS folder, and (2) that you have Windows Indexed the USERS folder.  Several steps here.

Comment: It did not work. I think because the files are online only, Windows can't index them? even though the files names are literally shown in my file explorer :(

Comment: Windows indexing cannot index on line only files

Comment: I posted an organized answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Indexing works with local files or files with local indexing.

With current indexing strategies in Windows, you cannot do indexed searching for your files.

Next best is to organize your cloud files and find things that way.

This is very effective. I have numerous organizations’ documents stored this way and can find things via file organization as effectively as Windows search which I also use.